# .addClass based on a span wrapped in two tables

Tags: jquery, parent, addclass, closest

I'm trying to add a class to a table.

`<table>` > `<tbody>` > `<tr>` > `<td>` > `<table>` > `<tbody>` > `<tr>` > `<td>` > `<span class="subcategory">`

So basically I'd like to add a class to the initial table based on the span.subcategory.
I have this:

```
$('span.subcategory').parent().closest("table").addClass('myClass');
```

But it only goes to the second table.

Comment: $("span.subcategory").closest("table").closest("table").addClass("myClass"); => that will do the trick, but it's far from an optimized code

Comment: @CédricBelin I don't think that would work. `closest` doesn't go up the DOM tree if the element itself satisfies the selector (so it would remain on the inner table even after the second `closest` invocation).

Comment: @Sime Vidas: I think you're right... oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span.subcategory').parents('table:last')
```

Comment: This assumes that there will be no more tables up the tree?

Comment: If you're sure that there will never be… :-)

Comment: @esycat If you nest three levels of tables, you deserve to be sent to a gulag in Siberia `:P`

Answer (score 1):

To get to the outer table:

```
$('span.subcategory').parents('table').eq(1).addClass('myClass');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ly5p2/)

Or, possibly:

```
$('span.subcategory').parents('table:has("table span.subcategory"):first').addClass('myClass');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ly5p2/1/)

Comment: Second one did work, but elijah's answer is less complicated... +1

Comment: Elijah's is only 'less complicated' *if* you've only got two tables (since his solution will always return the outer-most table). And, my apologies, but the first demo seems to work perfectly well. Which leads me to suggest that if it doesn't work for you in your own page, then there's something else going on in that page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.subcategory').closest('table').parent().closest('table').addClass('myClass');
```

I believe this should be more efficient, as it will traverse DOM tree only up to the second (outer) table.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
$('span.subcategory').closest('table')
    .parent().closest('table')
    .addClass('myClass');`
```

work?

Alternatively:

```
$('table:has(table:has(span.subcategory))').addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Yes, but this adds the class to both parent `table`s, I'm only trying to add it to the top parent `table`

Comment: I believe that adds the class to both TABLE elements.